# Woocommerce: what activates single-product-reviews.php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Some of the products have an option to leave a review and some don't. I noticed that the file single-product-reviews.php is not loaded in these products where there is no option to leave a review.

Does anyone know what in the theme decide whether to load the file single-product-reviews.php?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First condition for displaying product review is that theme should declare support for the plugin.

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

Plugin also provides option to enable / disable product review globally. Under `WooCommerce` -> `Settings` -> `Products`, there is checkbox `Enable product reviews`. If this is disabled, it applies globally and product reviews wont be displayed.

Review can also be enabled / disabled product wise. When you edit product, you can find `Advanced` tab under `Product Data` metabox. There is checkbox `Enable reviews`. With this you can turn on / off review product wise.

Product review loading is handled in `class-wc-template-loader.php`.

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', array( __CLASS__, 'comments_template_loader' ) );
```

Inside `comments_template_loader()` method you can see loading of single product review template.

```
foreach ( $check_dirs as $dir ) {
    if ( file_exists( trailingslashit( $dir ) . 'single-product-reviews.php' ) ) {
        return trailingslashit( $dir ) . 'single-product-reviews.php';
    }
}
```